# How would I add a while loop to this password verification script?

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, passwords

I have completed this assignment for my class but struggled with adding a while-loop to prompt the user to enter a new password if the previous attempt didn't meet required parameters.

**For this assignment we were not allowed to use regex.**

I'm newer to Python so I think the failing point here may be my understanding of boolean values in relation to while-loops. Ultimately, the assignment didn't require this function but I am completely stumped on how I could add it if need be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def main():
    #Prompting for a new password
    print("Hello! Welcome to newPasswordMaker, below are the requirements for a strong password. Please review the requirements and enter your new password for verification!\n\n")
    print("Your password must meet the following parameters:\n")
    print("- Must be greater than 8 characters and no more than 12 characters.")
    print("- Must not include any spaces.")
    print("- Must contain at least one digit")
    print("- Must contain at least one alphabetic letter\n")

    newPassword = input("Please enter your new password below:\n")
    print(finalCheck(newPassword))  

    

#--------FUNCTIONS---------

#Function to check for valid length of password
def lenChecker(newPassword):
    if len(newPassword) < 8:
        return False
    elif len(newPassword) > 12:
        return False
    return True

#Function to check for presence of spaces
def spaceChecker(newPassword):
    if " " in newPassword:
        return True
    return False    

#Function to confirm newPassword meets requirements of at least alpha and one numeral
def charChecker(newPassword):
    if not any(char.isalpha() for char in newPassword):
        return False
    elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in newPassword):
        return False
    return True   

#Function to pass all values through and return specific feedback!
 def finalCheck (newPassword):

    #Final pass to validate length of password:
    if(lenChecker(newPassword)== False):
        return "Your password must be at least 8 but no more than 12 characters."

    #Final pass to check for presence of " " in newPassword:
    elif (spaceChecker(newPassword)== True):
        return "Your password may not have any spaces in it."

    #Final pass for validation of alphabetics and numericals:
    elif (charChecker(newPassword)== False):
        return "Your password should contain at least one alphabetic AND one numerical character"
    #If all checks return as False:
    return "\nYour password passes all checks!\nCongrats on the new password!"


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just while your result is not your success message keep asking...

```
def main():
    #Prompting for a new password
    print("Hello! Welcome to newPasswordMaker, below are the requirements for a strong password. Please review the requirements and enter your new password for verification!\n\n")
    print("Your password must meet the following parameters:\n")
    print("- Must be greater than 8 characters and no more than 12 characters.")
    print("- Must not include any spaces.")
    print("- Must contain at least one digit")
    print("- Must contain at least one alphabetic letter\n")

    newPassword = input("Please enter your new password below:\n")
    result = finalCheck(newPassword)  
    success = "\nYour password passes all checks!\nCongrats on the new password!"
    while result != success:
         print(result)
         newPassword = input("Please enter your new password below:\n")
         result = finalCheck(newPassword)  
    print(result)
```